# SVN Checkout over RDP to local drive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rdp

if i want to ckeckout a SVN repo over a RDP-Connection to the local Drive it fails. I got the Message:
Can't move '\tsclient\C....svn\tmp\svn-D11963A0' to
'\tsclient\C....svn\pristin\79\7975aa7a459b4aee22785686443eef781a48fbe9.svn-base':

If i try to copy, cut or delete the svn-D11963A0 file it works. Also to rename this file, or create a new file with the name 7975aa7a459b4aee22785686443eef781a48fbe9.svn-base it works.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Greetings

Comment: How do you check out across Remote Desktop? Do you mean that you are doing a regular file copy with a directory that happens to be a Subversion working copy?

Comment: In the RDP settings i set under local device and resources the harddrive from my PC. In the remotesession i create a new folder on my local harddrive and try a SVN checkout to get a new working copy. I get the error message described above.  If i create a Subversion working copy on the remote server and copy it to my local hard drive, this works fine.

Comment: Subversion working copies are very resource intensive when it comes to file system manipulation. Having a working copy in a network share performs badly and is discouraged. Doing it through RDP is probably beyond design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it over RDP again and if I do a checkout more than once the files will be moved. But unfortunately it stops after 5 repetitions at the latest.